# Java Web Start (JNLP) Loading Message

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Is it possible to display a custom loading message when a user loads a java web start application from a webpage?  Maybe a progressbar or something similar.  Users with slow connections see "Java Loading..." for far too long while the jars are downloaded for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#206)(or see below), you can add your own splash screen, it looks like just an image in this case.  Also there are two issues the download time and the application startup time.  In java6 you can add an actual splash screen(component) and show progress bar etc.  But this would be for application startupup time and not download time.  If you look [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/quinn/entry/customizing_an_app_client_s), you can customize some text on the download screen.  At some point the user is going to have to take the time to download the files regardless of the connection speed, but once they have done it once, if you settings are correct, the files should be cached locally and it should start much faster the next time.

--FROM PAGE
How can I provide my own splash screen?

Java Web Start needs to put up the initial splash screen while Java is loading. For subsequent access, you can specify an image file to use for the splash screen in the JNLP file with the tag

where mysplash.jpg is the image file for your splash screen.  The first time your application runs, it will use the standard splash screen. After that, it will use the image you provide.